# How to check whether datarow is empty or not in C#

Tags: c#

Below is my `dr1` where I am comparing the value with `dt` using `dt.Select` when value matches with `dt` it returns `dr1` as `System.Data.DataRow[1]` if my `dt` doesnot match with value it returs `System.Data.DataRow[0]` I need to write the condition to exceute below lines of code where `dr1` is not zero. How can I do this

my datarow is becoming zero when there is no row matching

```
DataRow[] dr1 = DT.Select(name);
```

Comment: So just check the length... `if(dr1.Length > 0) { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check count of array. If count > 0 means dr1 has matching records else not.

```
if(dr1 != null && dr1.Count() > 0)
 {
//matching record found
  }
else
{
//No matching records
}
```

Comment: i had return in this way  if (dr1 != null && dr2 != null)
                            {

                                Read();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblmessage.Visible = true;
                                lblmessage.Text = "Please select same files";
                            } but its not working

Comment: Edited answer. Along with null you need to check count as well.

Comment: ok. I have added it. Even you can do if it solved the issue